# React - proptypes validation - return Error doesnt work but throw does

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

So, Im looking at the react proptypes options, and I want to check if the children is a specific type, its really simple, and as mentioned here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation I should return an Error object and not throw.
But when I return an Error object it doesn't print to the console, but if I throw an Error object everything works fine.

propTypes object:

```
const propTypes = {
        children: function(props, propName) {
            const children = props[propName];
            React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
                if (child.type !== Field) {
                    // doesnt work
                    return new Error('Error');
                }
                return;
            });
        }
    };

const propTypes = {
        children: function(props, propName) {
            const children = props[propName];
            React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
                if (child.type !== Field) {
                    // does work
                    throw new Error('Error');
                }
                return;
            });
        }
    };
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning from `forEach` loop doesn't make enclosing function return. What you should better do is either use simple `for` loop or [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```javascript
const propTypes = {
  children: function(props, propName) {
    const children = props[propName];
    const invalid = React.Children.some(children, child => child.type !== Field);
    if (invalid) {
      return new Error('Error');
    }
  }
};
```